# AngularJS - Passing data similar as url parameter?

Tags: angularjs

Hi need to put links on a html page using AngularJS. These links will redirect to an unique page (example contact.html), which depending of value on link will display a different result.

There is a crap example, but I think is enough to understand what I need to do... :)

**page1.html**

```
<a href="page2.html?x=hello">hello</a>
<a href="page2.html?x=goodbye">goodbye</a>
```

**page2.html**

```
if x=hello display "hello";
if x=goodbye display "goodbye".
```

How to do this in AngularJS?

******* UPDATE *******

Page 1:

```
<ons-button modifier="clean" ng-controller="xController" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html/#?x=hello', {closeMenu: true})">
  <img src="hello.jpg">
</ons-button>

<ons-button modifier="clean" ng-controller="xController" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html/#?x=goodbye', {closeMenu: true})">
  <img src="goodbye.jpg">
</ons-button>
```

Page 2:

```
<div class="page-content" ng-controller="xController">
  <p>***{{ x }}***</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('xController', ['$location', function ($location) { 
  var x = $location.search().x;
}]);
```

In page 2, the `<p>***{{ x }}***</p>` is not displaying "hello" or "goodbye" from **x** url parameter.

PS: the URL to get x parameter is not remote, it is local inside Cordova app (I don't know if it really matters...)

Comment: you didn't mention onsen ui in original post, and i am not familiar with it. you can try to search a seed project by using onsen ui and angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
$location.search().x
```

$location.search will return an object of all the URL parameters.

Comment: Could you please show me a code example of both pages to let it working? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In `page2.html`, you can use `$location` service to retrieve search parameters from url:

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$location', function($location){

    var searchParams = $location.search();

    if(searchParams.x === 'hello'){
         // display 'hello'
    }else if(searchParams.x === 'goodbye'){
         // display 'goodbye'
    }

}])
```

[API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: Could you please show me code of both pages to let working that?

Comment: well, if `page1.html` and `page2.html` are totally two separate angular application, then you don't need to write much codes in `page1.html`, just add two `a` elements as you described in original post. If you are using `ui-route` or `ng-route` to do the page switching, you need to setup your routing config, see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: I'm new with angular and js, so if you could take a look at my code, it will help me a lot. I have updated the post. Thank you very much!